# Passing function template specializations to a variadic template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-function

I have no problem passing the address of a function template specialization to a regular template function:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T) {}

template <typename A, typename B>
void foo(A, B) {}

int main()
{
    foo(&f<int>, &f<float>);
}
```

However, when I try to pass the same specializations to a variadic template:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T) {}

template <typename... A>
void bar(A...) {}

int main()
{
    bar(&f<int>, &f<float>);
}
```

I get the following compiler errors with GCC (I tried 4.6.1 and 4.7.0):

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:9:27: error: no matching function for call to 'bar(<unresolved overloaded function type>, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
test.cpp:9:27: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:5:6: note: template<class ... A> void bar(A ...)
test.cpp:5:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Why am I getting these errors?

Comment: `auto a = &f<int>` doesn't work either: `error: 'a' has incomplete type`

Comment: This works: `bar((void(*)(int))f<int>, (void(*)(double))f<double>);` but obviously that's not a solution. It just means (like the error said) it can't tell what type `&f<int>` is for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it might be a [bug in GCC that is possibly fixed in GCC 4.6.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50086) (I say possibly because it's not exactly the same, but does involve getting the address of a variadic template function).

Comment: Nice find! That looks like it's almost certainly the same issue. (I'll verify once I build a more recent 4.7.0).

Comment: Confirmed, it was the same issue.